# Call Activity with Custom Arguments

Tags: android, android-activity, arguments

I would like to ask about calling an Activity with arguments. I have seen many examples about it. But I would like to ask an explanation why it is somehow *"not easy"* or *"not simple"* to create(call) an activity with custom arguments.

I've seen many posts like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2139134/how-to-send-an-object-from-one-android-activity-to-another-using-intents) and others. People passing strings but not custom objects. Yes, they are passing custom objects by implementing serializable and parceable methods but that doesn't seem efficient (I might be wrong because haven't seen it). For **final** declared classes, it is even more work to do.

When we pass String with *putExtras(String name, String value)*, why is a function like *putExtras(String name, Object object)* not defined? wouldn't it be easier to pass any custom objects by that?

And about the complexity of the process, an explanation was given in the post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2139134/how-to-send-an-object-from-one-android-activity-to-another-using-intents)

> beacuse apps are in different processes, and have separate memory
>   address spaces, you cant just send pointer (reference) to memory block
>   in your process and expect it to be available in another process.

But, still, I couldn't find a reason that satisfy me or helps me to realize what I am not seeing. Okay, let's say apps are in different processes and their memory spaces are different. So are we copying the data to be passed into another activity's memory space? or at least, shouldn't the activities which belong to same application (I believe activities in an app has something common that addresses to its app) have the common memory space so that they could easily share or pass data?

I am just trying to clarify myself about this. I know Android should not be compared with Windows development but feels like it could be better if things were simpler. I know I am missing something about this, otherwise everyone knows simpler would be better. But what is the thing that prevents passing things easier?

Thanks.

Comment: I agree with this, and can only conclude the Android is built in a rather silly way. To force simple objects to be Serializable just to pass it from one Activity to another is just... insane. Sure, CommonsWare explains why, but if I was working as a designer of the Android OS, and I would come up with such a thing, I would fire myself from my job and ban myself from ever coding ever again ;-)

Answer (score 0):

> why is a function like putExtras(String name, Object object) not defined? wouldn't it be easier to pass any custom objects by that?

Because `startActivity()` always crosses a process boundary, and therefore whatever gets passed needs to be convertible into a byte array for transport.

> So are we copying the data to be passed into another activity's memory space?

We are copying data between processes.

> or at least, shouldn't the activities which belong to same application (I believe activities in an app has something common that addresses to its app) have the common memory space so that they could easily share or pass data?

Except that the primary work of `startActivity()` is not done by your application process, but rather by a core operating system process.

> I know Android should not be compared with Windows development but feels like it could be better if things were simpler.

A better analogy is Web development, where you do not pass objects between client and server, but rather data marshalled to/from strings or byte arrays.

Comment: Is really data passed to an activity being copied and not referenced? I think that is why Android does not allow passing objects. So there is no way passing an image between activities I guess.. Still trying to understand the reason "why".

Comment: @OmerHalit: "Is really data passed to an activity being copied and not referenced?" -- yes. "So there is no way passing an image between activities I guess" -- not via `Intent` extras, unless they're really small. "Still trying to understand the reason "why"" -- that's how they elected to write the operating system.

Comment: "that's how they elected to write the operating system" -- I need to find out why they elected this way. There must be a benefit if they elected so, or they are simply wrong. Just that I need to understand the architecture so that I know what I am doing but it is taking me long.. In web development, I understand because user and source not in the same place but in Android it is. Is this same in iOS development or simpler?

Answer (score 0):

Just as you have figured out yourself you pass data between activities through a Bundle, like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, MyActivity.class);
intent.putExtra(key, "some string");
intent.putExtra(key, true);
intent.putExtra(key, 1.5f);
```

The thing is that Intents and Bundles are a very versatile way of passing data not only between your own activities, but also to other applications, say by launching a messaging client and providing a predefined subject and body. This is very powerful but it is also a constraint. What if you like to pass MyFooClass? Well you can't do that since an Intent is an abstract way of performing an operation, not only within your own application. One might argue that Google should have made an exception for intents between your own activities, but I really don't see this as a very big problem.

You can, as you say yourself, serialize an object using serializable interface, but you could also serialize it as a JSON object. I would also say that if you need to pass complex data structures between activities you really need to rethink your design. You should probably have some global application state (in your Application or similar class) and only pass ids, keys or similar that you can use to look up the data from your application state.